# Fingerprint Scanner not working in Ubuntu

Tags: login, lenovo, thinkpad, scanner

My Lenovo Thinkpad-T470s has a built-in fingerprint scanner, but Ubuntu doesn't recognize it. I tried unlocking the settings by entering my password, but there was still no option for fingerprint login. I faced the same issue with Linux Mint. Interestingly, the fingerprint scanner works perfectly on Windows.

However, I was able to resolve the problem by following the instructions provided at github.com/uunicorn/python-validity#setting-up. These steps helped in detecting my fingerprint scanner, which wasn't being recognized before. Then, I made changes to the login and sudo file located in /etc/pam.d, and everything seemed to be going well. But upon restarting and attempting to log in using my fingerprint, it stated that the fingerprint was not recognized.

Edit: I tried enabling fingerprint for system authentication and it worked for login once at least and then it stopped working again.

Comment: Not all fingerprint scanners have drivers for the linux kernel

Comment: Try the instructions here. Let us know if they work https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity#setting-up

Comment: once you have set up the fingerprint reader, here is how to use it for login and for sudo. https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Lenovo_ThinkPad_T470s#Fingerprint_reader

Comment: I tried what you said and was able to get my fingerprint scanner working but when I try to login using it, it says fingerprint not match. I tried re-rolling my finger but that didnt fix my problem

Comment: Edit your question with the steps you followed, and mention the issue you are facing.

Comment: Also try https://github.com/uunicorn/python-validity#enabling-fingerprint-for-system-authentication In case it does not work with login, does it still work as a sudo replacement?

Comment: I enabled fingerprint for system authentication but still I am facing the issue that my fingerprint is not being matched. SEND HELP PLZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ